# Drupal: No Content is shown when not logged in

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, view, cck

I recently setup a drupal page and inserted content. After logging out I saw that nothing was shown. I've been investigating for several hours now and can't find what Im doing wrong.

The permission for the Anonymous User to "access content" is show, but somehow neither anything is shown in the menu nor in the content section.

The Startpage points to a view called frontpage and it works just fine, when logged in.

http://mobileaward.at/

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really programming related unless you're writing a custom content-type or something. Asking how to use Drupal is better elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, if you are not comfortable working directly with the database in the way xXx suggested, you can also go to /admin/content/node-settings on your site and click the "rebuild permissions" button.

Answer (score 2):

Found the Error....

Make sure to check your node_access table, as it might got emptied somehow, if thats the case execute following query to allow access to all pages by the anonymous user again:

```
INSERT  INTO  node_access(nid ,gid ,realm ,grant_view, grant_update , grant_delete)VALUES ( '0',  '0',  'all',  '1',  '0',  '0')
```

Comment: The possible reason in my case was lack of available disk space for mysql drupal db.